# Looking for good algorithm to run specific code on given time. (Arduino C program)

Tags: c, algorithm, time, arduino

I'm writing a timer/scheduler simple program for Arduino.

It's a c program, with 'main' loop that is running again and again.
Arduino has DS3231 RTC module connected to it and provides the current day-of-week, hour, minute, second, etc.

What I need to achieve is sending a specific string over the serial port, but in contrast to many examples about 'lighting a LED at a specific time' - I can't allow the code to run more than once.
So, if a normal 'light a LED on a specific time' just loops again and again the 'if' check and according to it sets the digital output 'HIGH' or 'LOW' (again and again) - I can't use this approach.

The approach I'm using now, and it works, is like this:
I made an array with the wanted times, and 'action code' for each time - all of them are Integers, like this:

```
const int A = 6;    // Action Array Size
  int ActionTimes[A][4] = {
    {6,18,37,1},
    {6,18,38,2},
    {5,15,20,11},
    {5,16,35,51},
    {5,16,40,52},
    {5,23,55,15}   
  };
```

Then, from the main loop I call a "Check" function that runs a 'for' loop to check if there is an action that should be run in this current time:

```
 int i;
  for ( i = 0; i < A; i++ ) {

    if ((dt.DayOfWeek()==ActionTimes[i][0]) && (dt.Hour()==ActionTimes[i][1]) && (dt.Minute()==ActionTimes[i][2]) && (dt.Second() < 2)) {
        RunMyAction(ActionTimes[i][3]);
}
```

And then - I have the 'action' function that runs the actual needed code, like this:

```
void RunMyAction(const int& MyActionCode)
{
  switch(MyActionCode) {
    case 1:
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);  // Turn the LED on by making the voltage LOW
      Serial.println("S041ONE");
      break;  
     case 2:
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
      Serial.println("S017ONE");
      break;        
     case 11:     //Before Knissat Shabat - Full status update.
      Serial.println("S01D00000D00ES02D01001100ES03D00101101ES04D1100D0DDES05D10011DDDE");
      delay(1000);
      break;
     case 15:     //Last GoodNight Shabat - Full status update.
      Serial.println("S01D00000000ES02D00000000ES03D00000100ES04D1000D00DES05D00011DDDE");
      delay(1500);
      break;
     case 51:
      Serial.println("S036OFE");
      delay(1500);
      break;
     case 52:
      Serial.println("S047OFES036ONE");
      delay(1500);
      break;
  }
}
```

That works for me and 'do the job' but I feel (algorithmically speaking) maybe it's not the best way to write it.

For example - all the actions and the needed times are hard-coded into the program itself. For any added action - I have to manually change the const of the array size, manually change the array definition, and add additional code to the switch function.

(Thought about excel-made #include files to merge into the array part and the switch function, but this also has to re-compile the program for every time/action change).

Would appreciate any insight about how to look at it for more professional, effective, way.

Many thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, I think you're asking two questions. 1) how to execute code only once at the right time 2) how to provide some sort of interface to edit the times and actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid executing the same action twice in a row, I'd add a global variable to hold the index into ActionTImes[] of the most recently executed action, then test that variable in the if statement.

```
int latestActionIndex = -1; // -1 so on startup we don't think we've executed ActionTimes[0].
```

then in the For loop:

```
if ((dt.DayOfWeek()==ActionTimes[i][0])
    && (dt.Hour()==ActionTimes[i][1])
    && (dt.Minute()==ActionTimes[i][2]
    && latestActionIndex != i)) {
  latestActionIndex = i; // note that we've run this action
  RunMyAction(ActionTimes[i][3]);
}
```

I removed the (dt.Second() < 2) from the if statement, because the action will likely execute within a second or so of dt.second() == 0, and the new variable keeps RunMyAction() from being executed more than once.